# Django models: requiring user to input either field, but not both or neither?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have an Image model

```
class Image(...
    # store file info
    image = ImageField(...
    # store link info
    url = URLField(...
    # storing either image or url is okay
    # storing both is NOT okay
    # storing neither is NOT okay
```

I want the user to be able to upload an image file or submit an image url to link to.  Is there a way for the model to require the user to have at least one of the two fields?

Comment: You could consider having a single field which was required, which either accepted an image or an url.

Answer (score 1):

In your **view**, you might have something like:

```
form = Image(request.POST or None)
```

When you're grabbing the data from the forum, you might have `form.cleaned_data['image']` and `form.cleaned_data['url']`.  If one's empty while the other isn't, proceed with whatever you wanted to do.  If both are empty, proceed with displaying the error.  form.cleaned_data is just a dictionary containing the form values, so you can check to see which ones are empty.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to consider both of them as *not required* and then handle the validation in your views, there you can check if either one is present , the form submission was successful, other ways you can output an error to the user.

It was just an idea of how to overcome the issue, i know it won't answer your question (though I think that's not possible in models , but i'm not sure)
 hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have following options

- Add [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method in your `Image` model. This will check if only one of field (image or url) is provided. Otherwise raise `ValidationError`.

  - This will handle conditions when you are saving objects using `ModelForm`.
- You need to also override [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) method of the model. In this check if you have only one of the field provided, otherwise raise `IntegrityError`.

  - This will handle cases when a attribute of object is saved individually.

Something like:

```
obj = Image.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
obj.url = some_url
obj.save()
```

- If you want to skip 2nd option, you must call `full_clean` method before saving each existing object.

like

```
obj = Image.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
obj.url = some_url
obj.full_clean() 
obj.save()
```